# YouTube becomes unusable (playback is slow & non responsive) after listening to music for a while in Firefox. How to fix it without a browser restart?

Tags: windows-10, firefox, dell-latitude

High-performance Dell Latitude laptop (Core i7, 32GB RAM) with Windows 10.

After simply listening to YouTube Music in Firefox tab for a few hours, YouTube performance decreases very bad.

Music playback still works ok, but I can't basically watch a video: video is frozen, only audio works, and seeking is non-responsive.

During this time, some of the `firefox` processes take 2-digits percentage of CPU usage. Killing those processes in an attempt to not kill the FF browser completely does not help.

The only fix for this is to restart the Firefox browser completely.

Any ideas about the cause?

Anything else that can be done (so that I don't have to restart the browser)?

I need to not restart the browser, because sometimes I keep a private window opened as well and I don't want to lose the session from there.

Comment: Have you disabled adblockers and other extensions? Ruling them out first would be key.

Comment: Something else to try would be https://addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/addon/auto-tab-discard/?utm_source=addons.mozilla.org&utm_medium=referral&utm_content=search which can give a right-click menu item for tabs that allows you to "discard" them. The tab is essentially unloaded and refreshing it should reload the data. It should be roughly equivalent to closing the browser, but only for that tab. Your first stop should be finding out *why* it is a problem to begin with, hence my first comment. My guess would be the Google crackdown on adblockers causing performance issues.

Comment: Do you have Adblock installed by chance? Firefox and Chrome browsers both have issues with Adblock (and others) in the last 90 days (Firefox) and as recently as this week (Chrome)

Comment: "YouTube began interrupting videos for those using advert blockers..." https://www.theregister.com/2023/11/21/ad_block_google/ Workaround: *download* the music and play from disk.